# Teradata SQL EXPAND + ACCUMULATE

Tags: sql, teradata

I have on-boarding data, counting IDs over time. I have expanded the data, but I also need to accumulate.

I have:

```
ONBOARDING_DATE ONBOARDED ONBOARDED_EXPANDED
12/06/2018                          
13/06/2018                          
14/06/2018            2            2
15/06/2018                         2
17/06/2018                         2
18/06/2018            5            5
19/06/2018                         5
20/06/2018                         5
```

I need it to accumulate as more IDs are being onboarded, but not able to find the right function that will combine with expand.

```
ONBOARDING_DATE ONBOARDED ONBOARDED_EXPANDED_ACCUMULATED
12/06/2018                        
13/06/2018                        
14/06/2018            2            2
15/06/2018                         2
17/06/2018                         2
18/06/2018            5            7
19/06/2018                         7
20/06/2018                         7
```

My script,

```
SELECT 

a.ONBOARDING_DATES
, b.ONBOARDED
, SUM(ONBOARDED) OVER ( PARTITION BY 1
                    ORDER BY ONBOARDING_DATE ASC
                    RESET WHEN ONBOARDED<>0 ) AS ONBOARDED_EXPANDED

FROM

        (
        SELECT 

        CAST(CALENDAR_DATE AS DATE) AS ONBOARDING_DATES FROM 
SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR

        WHERE ONBOARDING_DATES BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, - 9)  AND ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, + 9)

        ) a

LEFT JOIN
    (

            SELECT DISTINCT

            COUNT(ID) AS ONBOARDED
            , WAVE_DATE

            FROM ENV0.R_ONBOARDING

            WHERE WAVE_DATE IS NOT NULL

            GROUP BY WAVE_DATE

    ) b

    ON a.ONBOARDING_DATS = b.WAVE_DATE

    ORDER BY a.ONBOARDING_DATE
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to just want a cumulative sum:

```
select ONBOARDING_DATE, ONBOARDED,
       sum(onboarded) over (order by onboarding_date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as ONBOARDED_EXPANDED
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `RESET WHEN` can be rewritten using `LAST_VALUE` plus `IGNORE NULLS`, which results in a single STATS-step in Explain instead of two. And if you want to calculate both `ONBOARDED_EXPANDED` and `ONBOARDED_EXPANDED_ACCUMULATED` you can combine them in a single step, too:

```
SELECT 
   a.ONBOARDING_DATES
   ,b.ONBOARDED
   ,SUM(ONBOARDED) 
    OVER (ORDER BY ONBOARDING_DATE ASC
          ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDIND) AS ONBOARDED_EXPANDED
   ,LAST_VALUE(ONBOARDED IGNORE NULLS) 
    OVER (ORDER BY ONBOARDING_DATE ASC
          ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDIND) AS ONBOARDED_EXPANDED_ACCUMULATE
```

Same PARTITION, same ORDER combines both calcultions into a single step.